fixing array from being created until button is pressed
I am trying to make a to-do list, I need separate pages one for tasks and one for projects, I have an array that should get filled in once I input a form, but the array gets filled with multiple items after, I have found that every time I click either one of the page buttons, its creating a new array and then the add item button logs all of them, so I am assuming it has to do with how my pages are being loaded or how the code is being ran
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do It</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="side-menu">
            <button id="newBtn">+ New Item</button>
            <form id="formElement" style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Task Name">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" placeholder="Description">
                </li>
                <div id="button-options">
                    <li>
                        <select name="priority" id="priority">
                            <option value="priority" selected>Priority</option>
                            <option value="low">Low</option>
                            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                            <option value="high">High</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="date" name="dueDate" id="dueDate">
                    </li>
                </div>
                <button id="addBtn" type="submit">Add Item</button>
                <button id="cancelBtn" type="reset">Cancel</button>
            </form>

            <button class="nav-button" id="todayBtn">Home</button>
            <button class="nav-button" id="projectBtn">My Projects</button>
        </div>
        <div id="displayWrapper">
            <ul id="listDisplay" style="display: none;">
                
            </ul>
            <ul id="projectDisplay" style="display: none;">
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>

index.js
import './styles.css'; 
import { loadHomePage } from './homePage';
import { loadProjectPage } from './projectPage';

let myList = []; 
let projectList = []; 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    handlePageChange(loadHomePage, "todayBtn");
    
    document.getElementById("todayBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        handlePageChange(loadHomePage, "todayBtn");
    });

    document.getElementById("projectBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        handlePageChange(loadProjectPage, "projectBtn");
    });
});

function handlePageChange(loadPageFunction, activeButtonId) {
    document.getElementById("listDisplay").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("projectDisplay").style.display = 'none';

    loadPageFunction();  

    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-button");
    buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove("selectedMenu"));

    document.getElementById(activeButtonId).classList.add("selectedMenu");
}

export { myList, projectList };

homePage.js
export function loadHomePage() {
    const listDiv = document.getElementById("listDisplay");
    listDiv.style.display = 'block'; 
    listDiv.innerHTML = `<p>Home Page</p>`;  

    let myList = [];

    function listItem(title, description, dueDate, priority) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    function listLogic() {
        function displayItem() {
            listDiv.innerHTML = ''; 

            myList.forEach(function(item, index) {
                let itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
                itemContainer.classList.add("item-container");

                let titleElement = document.createElement("p");
                titleElement.textContent = `Title: ${item.title}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(titleElement);

                let descElement = document.createElement("p");
                descElement.textContent = `Description: ${item.description}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(descElement);

                let dueDateElement = document.createElement("p");
                dueDateElement.textContent = `Due Date: ${item.dueDate}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(dueDateElement);

                let priorityElement = document.createElement("p");
                priorityElement.textContent = `Priority: ${item.priority}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(priorityElement);

                let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
                deleteButton.classList.add("deleteBtn");
                deleteButton.textContent = "Delete Task";
                itemContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);

                deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myList.splice(index, 1);
                    displayItem();
                });

                listDiv.appendChild(itemContainer);
            });
        }

        function setupFormListener() {
            const formElement = document.getElementById("formElement");

            formElement.removeEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);

            function formSubmitHandler(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
                let desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
                let priority = document.getElementById("priority").value;
                let dueDate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;

                const newListItem = new listItem(title, desc, dueDate, priority);
                myList.push(newListItem);
                console.log(myList);

                displayItem();

                document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'none';
            }

            formElement.addEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);
        }

        setupFormListener();
        return { displayItem };
    }

    function buttonLogic() {
        function newBtn() {
            const newButton = document.getElementById("newBtn");
            newButton.removeEventListener('click', showForm);
            newButton.addEventListener('click', showForm);
        }

        function showForm() {
            document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function cancelBtn() {
            const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancelBtn');
            cancelButton.removeEventListener('click', hideForm);
            cancelButton.addEventListener('click', hideForm);
        }

        function hideForm() {
            document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'none';
        }

        return { newBtn, cancelBtn };
    }

    const buttonControls = buttonLogic();
    const listControls = listLogic();

    buttonControls.newBtn();
    buttonControls.cancelBtn();
    listControls.displayItem();
}

projectPage.js
export function loadProjectPage() {
    const projectDiv = document.getElementById("projectDisplay");
    projectDiv.style.display = 'block'; 
    projectDiv.innerHTML = `<p>Project Page</p>`; 

    let projectDisplay = [];

    function projectList(title, description, dueDate, priority) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    function listLogic() {
        function displayItem() {
            projectDiv.innerHTML = ''; 

            projectDisplay.forEach(function(item, index) {
                let itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
                itemContainer.classList.add("item-container");

                let titleElement = document.createElement("p");
                titleElement.textContent = `Title: ${item.title}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(titleElement);

                let descElement = document.createElement("p");
                descElement.textContent = `Description: ${item.description}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(descElement);

                let dueDateElement = document.createElement("p");
                dueDateElement.textContent = `Due Date: ${item.dueDate}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(dueDateElement);

                let priorityElement = document.createElement("p");
                priorityElement.textContent = `Priority: ${item.priority}`;
                itemContainer.appendChild(priorityElement);

                let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
                deleteButton.classList.add("deleteBtn");
                deleteButton.textContent = "Delete Task";
                itemContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);

                deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    projectDisplay.splice(index, 1);
                    displayItem();
                });

                projectDiv.appendChild(itemContainer);
            });
        }

        function setupFormListener() {
            const formElement = document.getElementById("formElement");

          
            formElement.removeEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);

            function formSubmitHandler(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
                let desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
                let priority = document.getElementById("priority").value;
                let dueDate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;

                const newprojectList = new projectList(title, desc, dueDate, priority);
                projectDisplay.push(newprojectList);
                console.log(projectDisplay);

                displayItem();

                document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'none';
            }

            formElement.addEventListener("submit", formSubmitHandler);
        }

        setupFormListener();
        return { displayItem };
    }

    function buttonLogic() {
        function newBtn() {
            const newButton = document.getElementById("newBtn");
            newButton.removeEventListener('click', showForm);
            newButton.addEventListener('click', showForm);
        }

        function showForm() {
            document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function cancelBtn() {
            const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancelBtn');
            cancelButton.removeEventListener('click', hideForm);
            cancelButton.addEventListener('click', hideForm);
        }

        function hideForm() {
            document.getElementById('formElement').style.display = 'none';
        }

        return { newBtn, cancelBtn };
    }

    const buttonControls = buttonLogic();
    const listControls = listLogic();

    buttonControls.newBtn();
    buttonControls.cancelBtn();
    listControls.displayItem();
}

I can't really figure out whats happening

Please consider doing some debugging to narrow down where the issue is happening

since you load both homePAge and projectPage, and they both add an event listener to the same form submit ... of course both run when you click submit.

Also, unrelated: if you're writing normal HTML + JS, you don't need the DOMContentLoaded event. Just put the script tags in your <head> with the async and defer attributes added (no values, just those attribute names), and you're done: your script now loads in parallel with your page (so it doesn't block anything), and it doesn't run until the DOM is ready. With the added note that if you're writing modern ESM and your script has type="module", those already automatically defer, so those never need to wait for a DOMContentLoaded event.

(and having said that: there's not much point to using webpack here, if you're just writing normal JS, using ESM without bundling is going to perform just as well in your particular case)

Indeed, that's what I mentioned too. Super convenient when writing modern JS. (but webpack will happily turn modern ESM JS into UMD or some other non-ESM bundle depending on the config used, so you want to cover all bases)

ahh, didn't see the edited version :p
